# One Enum vs Multiple Enums

Tags: java, sql, database, data

I am developing an application where a user submits a mission and other users accept the mission.

Pretty simple.

I want to keep a track of the mission progress status and store it into a database.

Which would be more appropriately

1. having the following enums in a database column:

   PRICE_NEGOTIATION,
   DEPOSIT_NEGOTIATION,
   MISSION_STARTED,
   DEMO_RECEIVED,
   DEMO_APPROVED,
   DEMO_UNAPPROVED,
   PAYMENT_DONE,
   PAYMENT_PENDING,

   PRICE_NEGOTIATION_UNAPPROVED_BY_CREATOR,
   PRICE_NEGOTIATION_UNAPPROVED_BY_ACCEPTOR,
   DEPOSIT_NEGOTIATION_UNAPPROVED_BY_CREATOR,
   DEPOSIT_NEGOTIATION_UNAPPROVED_BY_ACCEPTOR,
   MISSION_CANCELED_AFTER_START_BY_CREATOR,
   MISSION_CANCELED_AFTER_START_BY_ACCEPTOR,
   MISSION_CANCELED_AFTER_DEMO_UNAPPROVEMENT,

and so on..

2. having more than one column in the database where one of them gives a **cancel reason**, another one that holds **who canceled the mission** and another one about the **payment status**.

any better suggestions?

10x in advance and sorry if the question is too much opinion based.